# Can I use one parse database for an iOS app and a website? - using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

So if I explain what I'm trying to do, and someone can hopefully know if this is possible.

I have an iOS app I've made in Swift and this is connected to my Parse database. Data is pulled from Parse to my app and populates a TableView.

Instead of myself having to manually add data to the Parse table on the Parse site, Ideally it would be good to make a basic website that myself and select others can go to, and complete a form, save it, and then that data gets sent to my Parse database, and updates/adds this data to my iOS app.

But I want to know if I can have 2 different platforms sent to the same Parse database which is set up to work on iOS?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is what it is built for :D

Comment: @Fogmeister I hope so, but i'm a little confused, as when I set up that database, it asks me what platform I'm using, so I've obviously selected iOS and Swift. So how can this now work with a different coding language?

Comment: That quick setup is not for Parse. It's mainly for you. The setup does do some parse stuff. If you go into settings for your app on parse you will see all the setup that is needed for web, android, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Look at in your app setting on Parse Browser, that you have the keys for all platforms.

https://parse.com/apps/[YOUR-APP-NAME]/edit#keys